# Не могу добавить расширение Emmet для Brackets на Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux, linux-mint, emmet

Жму на значок Расширения. Начинает бесконечно долго крутится значок загрузки. Может есть другие способы установить еммет?

Answer (score 1):

[Emmet plugin for Brackets editor](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet#readme)

[image: Brackets]

Comment: Я копировал в терминал эти строки из ручной установки. Ничего не получается. Про первый способ я уже говорил, он не работает у меня

Comment: repo это репозиторий так? Хранилище программ, так? . Клонировать это repo. Какое это? Где мне его взять для начала что бы клонировать?

Comment: sudo apt install git, если не установлен. cd ~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user/ Далее git clone https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet Далее cd ~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user/brackets-emmet и npm install. Есть готовый пакет http://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/brackets-emmet/brackets-emmet-1.2.2.zip Сам его не ставил. Дать никаких гарантий не могу

Comment: cd ~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user/ Пишет: слишком много аргументов

Comment: У меня путь для установки cd /home/user/.config/Brackets/extensions/user/ ну и сам установленный плагин cd /home/user/.config/Brackets/extensions/user/brackets-emmet. Естественно, что у Вас будет  /home/Ваш профиль/.config/Brackets и т.д.

Comment: у меня в папке home есть каталог vladimir/ в нём почти все каталоги на русском языке типа видео, документы, загрузки и т.д. ЕСТЬ ПРАВДА ОДИН КАТАЛОГ ТАМ snap в нем каталог brackets - > в нём ещё три пустых каталога 139, common и current

Comment: Ввёл git clone адрес .......
Пишет fatal: репозиторий «github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet» не существует

Comment: А Вы уверены, что с Вашими знаниями Вы сможете собрать plugin с помощью npm? Запустите терминал и выполнить коммаду ls -al для информации. Решение: Запускаете brackets. Меню Debug-Switch Language- C System Default на русский и Reload Brackets Далее просто выходите из программы. При следующем запуске меню на русском и плагины должны ставиться. Были проблемы с переключением языка при запуске brackets через меню. Запускал в терминале /snap/bin/brackets

Answer (score 0):

Решил поставить brackets на Linux Mint 20 Ulyana(Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

```
Вариант с apt install snapd
snap install brackets --classic мне не нравится.
```

Поблема с отображением и обновлением плагинов.

```
Решение:
Запускаете brackets.
Меню Debug - Switch Language- C System Default на русский и Reload Brackets
Далее просто выходите из программы.
При следующем запуске меню на русском и плагины должны ставиться.
Были проблемы с переключением языка при запуске brackets через меню.
```

Запускал в терминале /snap/bin/brackets

Brackets есть и на [Flathub](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/io.brackets.Brackets)

Скачал https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/download/release-1.14.1/Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb

```
Лучше так не делать dpkg -i Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb
После такого приходится запускать apt --fix-broken install
Через gdebi и gdebi-core установка тоже не проходит. Проблемы с libcurl3.
```

Почитал https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14786

```
dpkg-deb -R ./Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb Brackets
sed -i 's/libcurl3/libcurl3 | libcurl4/' Brackets/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b Brackets Brackets-fixed.deb
sudo apt install -f ./Brackets-fixed.deb
```

Emmet plugin нашелся
[image: Emmet plugin]

Ну и поставился
[image: Install]

Comment: на 32-разрядную линукс пойдет программа Brackets.Release.1.14.1.64-bit.deb?

Comment: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/releases/download/release-1.14.1/Brackets.Release.1.14.1.32-bit.deb Есть же Brackets.Release.1.14.1.32-bit.deb